# Numbering of Questions in Different Way

Tags: lists, numbering, enumerate

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
Exercise-1
\end{center}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item 1st question.
  \item 2nd question.
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item sub numbering of 2nd question.
    \item sub numbering of 2nd question.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Here the output is:

```
Exercise-1 
1. 1st question. 
2. 2nd question. 
  (a) sub numbering of 2nd question. 
  (b) sub numbering of 2nd question
```

But I want to get the following outputs:

```
Exercise-1 
(a) 1st question. 
(b) 2nd question. 
  (i) sub numbering of 2nd question. 
  (ii) sub numbering of 2nd question.
```

OR

```
Exercise-1 
(i) 1st question. 
(ii) 2nd question.
  (a) sub numbering of 2nd question.
  (b) sub numbering of 2nd question.
```

Comment: Here the output is :
Exercise-1  
1. 1st question.
2. 2nd question.
 (a) sub numbering of 2nd question.
 (b) sub numbering of 2nd question

But I want to get the following outputs :

Exercise-1
(a) 1st question.
(b) 2nd question.
  (i) sub numbering of 2nd question.
  (ii) sub numbering of 2nd question.
  

OR



Exercise-1
(i) 1st question.
(ii) 2nd question.
  (a) sub numbering of 2nd question.
  (b) sub numbering of 2nd question.

Comment: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Please always put the question into the actual post, not into a comment below it.

Comment: Please don't post your question in a comment. In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Comment: @MdKutubuddinSardar: Even though this question did receive quite a large number of answers, I think your future questions would be even better if you put a bit more work in. It's generally appreciated if you show that you've done some research: Show what you've tried, link to questions that cover similar problems and explain why the answers don't work in your case.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`enumerate` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumerate) provides a simple mechanism to change the labels.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
Exercise~1
\end{center}

\begin{enumerate}[1.]
  \item 1st question.
  \item 2nd question.
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item sub numbering of 2nd question.
    \item sub numbering of 2nd question.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{center}
  Excerise~2
\end{center}

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
  \item 1st question.
  \item 2nd question.
  \begin{enumerate}[(i)]
    \item sub numbering of 2nd question.
    \item sub numbering of 2nd question.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

For more control over lists, including setting default labels, the [`enumitem` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) can be recommended.

Answer (score 8):

This is easily done by the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package. Here it is for your first case.

Here, the first level `enumerate` environment gets `(\roman)` labels through the `\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=(\roman*)}` setting and the second level gets `(\alph)` labels through `\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=(\alph*)}`. The syntax for `\setlist` is `\setlist[<listname>,<level>]{<format>}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=(\roman*)}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=(\alph*)}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
Exercise-1
\end{center}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item 1st question.
  \item 2nd question.
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item sub numbering of 2nd question.
    \item sub numbering of 2nd question.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit

I failed to mention that you *can* use [`enumerate`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate)-like syntax with the `shortlabels` options.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
Exercise-1
\end{center}

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
  \item 1st question.
  \item 2nd question.
  \begin{enumerate}[(i)]
    \item sub numbering of 2nd question.
    \item sub numbering of 2nd question.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{center}
Exercise-2
\end{center}

\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
  \item 1st question.
  \item 2nd question.
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item sub numbering of 2nd question.
    \item sub numbering of 2nd question.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can pass the "numbering" of your choice an an optional argument to the `\item` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
Exercise-1
\end{center}

\begin{enumerate}
 \item[(a)] 1st question.
 \item[(b)] 2nd question.
 \begin{enumerate}
  \item[(i)] sub numbering of 2nd question.
  \item[(ii)] sub numbering of 2nd question.
 \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

This is a manual change, however. To change it automatically, you have to define `\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\roman{enumi})}` - at least for the top level. You can probably change the lower levels too. For even more flexibility, you can use the `enumitem` package.

Answer (score 4):

You need to redefine the markers that are used for the enumerate.  These are controlled by the command `\theenumi` (for top level of enumerate list `\theenumii` for second level etc.).  The marker options are then set to one of `arabic,alph,Alph,Roman or roman`.  Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

%Redefine the first level
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\roman{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\theenumi)}

%Redefine the second level
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\alph{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{(\theenumii)}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
Exercise-1
\end{center}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item 1st question.
  \item 2nd question.
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item sub numbering of 2nd question.
    \item sub numbering of 2nd question.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```